# How do i log at runtime into a console with chromium?

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, chromium

I tried to log a message into the console at runtime when the function Document::CreateElementForBinding is used in the browser but it doesn't work. I tried with

```
PLOG(ERROR) << "Document::CreateElementForBinding()";
LOG(INFO) << "Document::CreateElementForBinding()";
DLOG(INFO) << "Document::CreateElementForBinding()";
VLOG(1) << "Document::CreateElementForBinding()";
DPLOG(ERROR) << "Document::CreateElementForBinding()";
```

and i also tested with printf and cout but i doesn't work even if i use the flag --enable-logging --v=1 and it has been compiled with the argument is_debug set to true.

Comment: What console are you referring to? Chromium's dev tool's console or a log file which is created when Chromium is invoked with those arguments?

Comment: Also the logging methods that you have used will log the specified data to `chrome_debug.log` file.

Comment: @Asesh Hey, Thank you for your answer!
I want a separate console (cmd) that i can log info to at runtime.